# Lenovo Laptop Login Error Message

Tags: error-logging

When I log into my Lenovo laptop, a system error message appears. After clicking the Ok four times it disappears. what is the problem and the solution?

[image]

Comment: https://pelegit.co.il/what-is-btweb-exe-and-how-to-fix-btweb-exe/

Comment: @Tetsujin that site gives bad (computergenerated) advice.

Answer (score 1):

[A Bittorrent client](https://www.bittorrent.com/nl/products/win/bittorrent-web-free/) tries to start when starting your computer. You can uninstall it or disable it in the Startup tab of the Task Manager. I would recommend uninstalling it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I do have Utorrent in my laptop. But i use it frequently, so is uninstalling it the only solution. What if i let the error remain, any harm to the programs?

Comment: This is not related to Utorrent. It is another bittorrent client called BitTorrent Web. If you want to use Bittorrent Web again you can re-install it. Hopefully then the message no longer appears. But Utorrent is probably a better choice. Both programs do the same task.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I remember I installed it once, but uninstalled long time ago. It is not in the programs lists.

Comment: Hm, there is a file called btweb.exe left on your computer though! It is probably in C:\Program Files. You can also check the Startup tab of the Task Manager to ensure it does not start when the computer starts. Another option is to install bittorrent web and then uninstall it.

Comment: hopefully installing it and then uninstalling it will get rid of all the traces.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.